# Webpack: resolve alias fallback

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm building a webapplication as composer package. 
Now I want to provide a basic theme with the option to extend this theme from the package. 
I was thinking about using a fallback for import aliasing in webpack.

So I often use `import Module from '@default/js/module'`. @default is aliased to the directory in my vendor modules. It would be great if I could alias the @default to a local dependency with a fallback to the vendor directory.

Is this possible?

Comment: Hi! did you find a solution?

Comment: I ended up using this: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/6817#issuecomment-542448438

Comment: yea, thanks, it also works for me!